# Filtering and paging not working in .NET Core 2.1 EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I try to apply filter and pagination to my GET query. Event when filter and pagination is not null and code reach inside the IF's, query always return all categories. What's the problem?

```
public async Task<List<Category>> GetListAsync(CategoryListFilter filter = null, Paging paging = null)
{
    var categories = _context.Categories
        .Include(category => category.Image)
        .Include(category => category.Parent)
        .Include(category => category.CategoryProperties)
            .ThenInclude(property => property.Property)
                .ThenInclude(property => property.ValueType)
                    .ThenInclude(valueType => valueType.InputType);

    if (filter != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.SearchText))
    {
        categories
            .Where(category => category.Title.Contains(filter.SearchText));
    }

    if(paging != null)
    {
        categories
            .Skip(paging.Offset)
            .Take(paging.Limit);
    }

    return await categories.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: `categories.Where(..)` returns a queryable, it won't affect the `categories` object at all.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely miss

```
categories = categories
            .Skip(paging.Offset)
            .Take(paging.Limit);
```

Without it, you call both but discard the result.

The same applies to the `Where` clause.

(note that this possibly requires providing an explicit type for `categories` so that both left and right side of the assignment are of the `IQueryable<Category>`)